# Are these knee walls load bearing

Tags: attic, storage

I bought a new construction house a few years ago and the attic was advertised as ready to be converted to a rec room.  It is mostly framed, with knee walls and has lighting, an initial gfci outlet and Ethernet run.

I would like to convert two of the knee wall areas to storage space but would need to remove some of the studs. Can you tell by these pictures if the knee wall studs are load bearing. Can I remove some for easier access for cabinets or doors.

I included the furnace area for reference. I wouldn't cut into those, I plan to build a closet around the furnace.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you frame your new opening like any other door or window the question is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a new build, you should be able to check the plans.

Eyeballing it, probably (almost certainly) not load-bearing. Single top plate, no header over furnace area opening, and clearly not part of a "spare room truss" structure (which is the most likely form of structural kneewall in the present era.)